# wget is giving 401 unautorized with a certain user on a linux machine all other user including root are able to download without issues

Tags: linux, wget

wget is giving 401 unautorized with a certain user on a linux machine all other user including root are able to download without issues

Checking on wget version between users it is the same , checking the env for users there is no differences other than the name of the home directory

only difference I could see is the Authorization: Basic in the wget debug for the run on the failing user is different.

failed user wget with username and password file to download file